# why does Google maps crash everytime the call button is clicked on android

Tags: android, eclipse

I think its due to a problem with the manifest can anyone or someone whos experienced this problem before help? ive too many classes to upload but ive attached the mainfest because i believe its causing the crash, if anyone can think of anything that else could cause this i can upload more class files ive been trying to fix this for 2 day, any help will be appreciated greatly

Below is also the runmapfragment which is used to host the google maps , the issue could also be in this class but the codes not throwing any errors if anybody wants to see any more code i can add more class files, ive no idea why maps is crashing

EDIT the following code was generated from the logcat anybody any suggestions on how to fix this?
 Process: com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal, PID: 15232
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal"

        android:versionName="1.0">

        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
        enter code here
        <permission
            android:name="com.exmaple.ryansfitnesspalreal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
            android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.example.ryansfitnesspal.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>

        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

        <uses-feature android:required="true" android:name="android.hardware.location.gps"/>
        <uses-feature android:required="true" android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"/>

        <application android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:allowBackup="false"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
            <activity android:name=".RunListActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".RunActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <activity android:name=".RunMapActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name" />
            <receiver android:name=".TrackingLocationReceiver"
                android:exported="false">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal.ACTION_LOCATION"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </receiver>
        <!-- Debug: AIzaSyADp90_tS0poJoVaPqMORxsNoeDqjiCxS8 -->
                  <meta-data
                      android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                      android:value="AIzaSyADp90_tS0poJoVaPqMORxsNoeDqjiCxS8"
                      />
              </application>

          </manifest>
```

---

```
package com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal;

/**
 * Created by RyanDesktop on 17/12/2014.
 */
import java.util.Date;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager;
import android.support.v4.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks;
import android.support.v4.content.Loader;
import android.view.Display;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal.RunDatabaseHelper.LocationCursor;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdate;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

public class RunMapFragment extends SupportMapFragment implements LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    private static final String ARG_RUN_ID = "RUN_ID";
    private static final int LOAD_LOCATIONS = 0;

    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LocationCursor mLocationCursor;

    public static RunMapFragment newInstance(long runId) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putLong(ARG_RUN_ID, runId);
        RunMapFragment rf = new RunMapFragment();
        rf.setArguments(args);
        return rf;
    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // check for a Run ID as an argument, and find the run
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        if (args != null) {
            long runId = args.getLong(ARG_RUN_ID, -1);
            if (runId != -1) {
                LoaderManager lm = getLoaderManager();
                lm.initLoader(LOAD_LOCATIONS, args, this);
            }
        }
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup parent, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = super.onCreateView(inflater, parent, savedInstanceState);

        // stash a reference to the GoogleMap
        mGoogleMap = getMap();
        // show the user's location
        mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        return v;
    }



    private void updateUI() {
        if (mGoogleMap == null || mLocationCursor == null)
            return;

        PolylineOptions line = new PolylineOptions();
        // also create a LatLngBounds so we can zoom to fit
        LatLngBounds.Builder latLngBuilder = new LatLngBounds.Builder();
        // iterate over the locations
        mLocationCursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!mLocationCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            Location loc = mLocationCursor.getLocation();
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(loc.getLatitude(), loc.getLongitude());

            // if this is the first location, add a marker for it
            if (mLocationCursor.isFirst()) {
                String startDate = new Date(loc.getTime()).toString();
                MarkerOptions startMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(getResources().getString(R.string.run_start))
                        .snippet(getResources().getString(R.string.run_started_at_format, startDate));
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(startMarkerOptions);
            } else if (mLocationCursor.isLast()) {
                // if this is the last location, and not also the first, add a marker
                String endDate = new Date(loc.getTime()).toString();
                MarkerOptions finishMarkerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(latLng)
                        .title(getResources().getString(R.string.run_finish))
                        .snippet(getResources().getString(R.string.run_finished_at_format, endDate));
                mGoogleMap.addMarker(finishMarkerOptions);
            }

            line.add(latLng);
            latLngBuilder.include(latLng);
            mLocationCursor.moveToNext();
        }
        // add the polyline to the map
        mGoogleMap.addPolyline(line);
        // make the map zoom to show the track, with some padding
        // use the size of the current display in pixels as a bounding box
        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        // construct a movement instruction for the map camera
        CameraUpdate movement = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(latLngBuilder.build(),
                display.getWidth(), display.getHeight(), 15);
        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(movement);
    }

    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        return new LocationListCursorLoader(getActivity(), args.getLong(ARG_RUN_ID, -1));
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor cursor) {
        mLocationCursor = (LocationCursor)cursor;
        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        // stop using the data
        mLocationCursor.close();
        mLocationCursor = null;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please include the exception stack trace from logcat.  Then we don't have to guess what the error is.

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: The Maps API requires the additional following permissions to be set in the AndroidManifest.xml to ensure a correct behavior:
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

Comment: So what's your problem?  The error is clear and simple.  You need to add that permission.

Answer (score 0):

the issue is for sure not the manifest. post whatever activity is hosting your GoogleMap. Sorry for posting an answer, not enough rep to comment

Comment: Because you don't have enough rep to comment does not excuse posting a comment as an answer.

Comment: I disagree, people should have the opportunity to ask for more information and edit in an answer to earn rep.

Comment: @DaveS Well of course the community gets to decide that, and the community curated rules are clear that comments should NOT be posted as answers.  The aim is to make sure that answers are just that, answers!

Comment: I mean technically yes, however it's acceptable to post an attempt at an answer and edit it later after you gain more information. Either way he should be able to comment soon.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you have a button that attempts to use the device's phone capabilities and it's crashing because of insufficient permissions then you need these two lines.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

Additionally if you still want to support tablets that don't have phone capabilities, make sure you include this line

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the `ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE` permission to your manifest.

[Documentation.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specify_permissions)

Comment: Yeah i added it but it created a new error message Process: com.example.ryansfitnesspalreal, PID: 15232 java.lang.IllegalStateException: no included points, have you any ideas?

Comment: Start with the full stacktrace and search for something like `android google maps "no included points"`.